# To put references to respective data buffers as member structs OR define local arrays inside the function instead?

Tags: c, embedded

So I'm trying to figure out if I should be allocating a local buffer inside the interrupt handler or it should be defined in the `main` as static global and then have a struct member's pointer point to it.

```
int tx_buffer[10] = {1,2,4};
int rx_buffer[10];
Data data;

int main(void) {
    data.txPtr = tx_buffer;
    data.rxPtr = rx_buffer;
    enable_irq();
}
void IRQ_Handler(Data *data) { // interrupt handler
    transmit_data(data, data->txPr, data->rxPtr);
}
void transmit_data(Data *data, int *tx, int *rx) {
   // ....
}
```

For that, I was wondering if it'd be useful to determine the stack usage of the function and see if I have enough.

Following is the capture from Stack Analyzer on Eclipse. I'm not super sure about local/max cost - thought it referred to the usage/size but the size of the individual component inside the IRQ handler doesn't match up.

[Stack Analyzer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7lkA.png)

Comment: Can you also add an example of the allocation inside the IRQ ?